# Populate HTML input fields using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to get data from a database using ajax and pass it into an HTML input field. I've tried this ..but i have receive [Object object] into my input field

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.get("api/users?page=1", function(e){ 
    $('#firstName').val(e)
 })
})
```

Comment: Log the response to console so you can see the return object and access the values from it. Also show a sample of the result from the ajax request. You are passing the full response object as value to the input that's why its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just loop through it, e.data is the array you have to loop through

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.get("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1", function(e){ 
   //  console.log(e);
    $.each( e.data, function( key, value ) {
          console.log(value.first_name);
        // you can use avatar,id,lastname, like this,
    });
 })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, I've received this error "Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1". Any suggestions?

Comment: check now , its because your json has array for data and page, etc keys, but you only need data, and before this code was starting loop with 1st element which is "page"

Comment: you welcome , would be great if you accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Because response data json object. You can use this:

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
$.get("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1", function(e){ 
   $('firstName').val(JSON.stringify(e));
 })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `getJSON()` function to simplify

```
  $(document).ready() function {
      $.getJSON("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1", function(data) {
         $.each (data.data, function (i) {
           $('#firstName').val(data[i].first_name);
         }); 
      });
    };
```